# Adding font on TCPDF

Tags: prestashop, tcpdf

I have tried reading through the documentation on TCPDF and am having trouble adding a custom font "Georgia" to TCPDF for invoicing on Prestashop's ecommerce system.

I have been trying to use this documentation,

http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

I'm trying to figure out where to add the following:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/themes/MYTHEME/fonts/Georgia.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);

$pdf->SetFont('georgia', '', 14, '', 'false');
```

Do I add this into /classes/pdf/PDF.php anywhere in the document? I then go ahead and change on PDFGenerator.php:

```
const DEFAULT_FONT = 'helvetica';
```

to

```
const DEFAULT_FONT = 'georgia';
```

I'm a bit of a newbie and I can't figure this one out, not surprisingly, but I feel that I am close!

Would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TCPDF, `addTTFfont` needs to have **write** access to the `fonts` folder. You only need to run the function `addTTFfont` once which causes a TCPDF version of the font to be made.

After that, it is just a matter of using `SetFont` to reference this value. I believe you no longer need to keep the original .ttf file as a result of this conversion.

Comment: As iWizardPro stated, you only need to do the add operation once and then use the SetFont().  
There is a command line utility in the tools folder for the add / convert step.  
The steps I took were:  
- download a font.ttf file into the fonts/ folder  
- run the utility to convert:  
./tcpdf_addfont.php -t TrueType -i ../fonts/Consolas.ttf